# How can I fix the Content Security Policy error to make 3rd party API requests in my Stripe App UI extension?

Tags: stripe-payments, content-security-policy, stripe-apps

When making a http request to "https://example.com/api" - the console throws an error

`Refused to connect to...because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src http://localhost:*...`

[image]

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

To make 3rd party API requests in your UI extension you mus specify the endpoints to be allowlisted in your `"content_security_policy": { "connect-src": [] }` 
You can use the Stripe CLI to grant the URL permission:

```
stripe apps grant url "https://*.api.example.com/path/" "Send data to example service..."
```

For full reference, see the Stripe Apps [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-apps/build-ui#use-third-party-apis).